# Why does barbecue's setBarWidth(int barWidth) method uses int parameter?

Tags: java, width, barcode, barbecue

So I can only give an integer as barwidth parameter but if I give 1 to the method my barcode is too narrow and if I give 2 to it, the barcode is too wide.
How could I solve this problem? I could modify the sourcecode of barbecue, but in the first round I would like to find an other solution if it's possible.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I got the answer. It sets the width of the thinnest bar in **pixels**. There is no half pixel or such thing, so that's why it's an int. But I still don't know how to set the proper size of my barcode.